# How to sort internal value of multidimensional dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, multidimensional-array, scheduling

I am creating a Windows service which controls a bunch of other processes but there is a need for the internal processes to run to their own schedules.
Each schedule is relatively simple with only the choice of which days of the week they run on, when the process should start and when it should stop.

My thoughts are to have a multidimensional dictionary such as below

```
Dictionary<string, TimeSpan> OnOff = new Dictionary<string,TimeSpan>();
OnOff.Add("Start", TimeSpan.Parse("09:00"));
OnOff.Add("Stop", TimeSpan.Parse("17:00"));

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>> Process = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,TimeSpan>>();
Process.Add("Process1", OnOff);

Dictionary<DayOfWeek, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>>> schedule = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,TimeSpan>>>();
schedule.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday, Process);
```

And to sort the "Process" dictionary by the closest of the "OnOff" TimeSpans before using a Simple Timer to act on the next action for the process when the TimeSpan arrives.

My issue with this plan is the sorting of the TimeSpans, and finding which of the "Start" / "Stop" actions contains the closest TimeSpan to sort by. Plus the fact that it could be a different action of each process that contains the closest TimeSpan.

Or can anyone think of a simpler way of achieving the same type of results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the schedule information is always present in the App.Config file I decided I didn't need to store it elsewhere.
The way I dealt with the scheduling was to find all the processes that needed actioning in the nearest future and only store those process details, the schedule time and the action required.

Then I simply ran a timer, and at the schedule time, performed the start or stop action.
Once all those processes were dealt with, I looked over the App.Config again and found the next list of processes to deal with.

```
    // The method that will be called when the schedule thread is started
    private void ProcessSchedule()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

        // work out the length of time between now and the schedule time
        string today = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyy");
        DateTime abaseTime = Convert.ToDateTime(today);
        TimeSpan scheduleTime = schedules.First().Value.ActionTime;
        DateTime actionTime = abaseTime.Add(scheduleTime);


        // log the schedule is starting
        if (log.IsInfoEnabled) log.Info(String.Format("Schedule created. Next action will take place at {0}", actionTime.ToString()));

        while (Running)
        {
            // this kills this process
            if (threadStop.WaitOne(0))
            {
                if (log.IsInfoEnabled) log.Info(String.Format("Schedules cancelled"));
                break;
            }

            if (DateTime.Now < actionTime)
            {
                //sleep 5 seconds before checking again. If we go any longer we keep our service from shutting down when it needs to.
                threadStop.WaitOne(5000);
                continue;
            }

            // tell the service control that it can action the schedules now
            ServiceControl.actionSchedule.Set();

            break;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just keep a structure

```
`class ProcessInfo
{
String ProcessID;
TimeSpan startTime;
TimeSpan endTime;
}`
```

and keep the structure of the Dictionary simple 
`Dictionary<string,ProcessInfo> schedule = new Dictionary<string,ProcessInfo>();`
just create a new object of **processinfo** when you need to add to list

Comment: I appreciate there are different ways to store the data - such as in a class / struct but the problems still remain of having to sort the data and account for the day of the week.

Comment: you can run a sort function/algorithm periodically and store the processes to run in an index

Comment: sorry it just occurred to me rather than just keeping ProcessInfo you should keep an **array** of processInfo and if you want sort that array by using a  simple sorting algorithm.